# Adding custom icons to the shipping options in Woocommerce Cart and Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add icons to the shipping options in Woocommerce Cart and Checkout.

For example in the "local pickup" option I want to show a little store icon beside the option just like this: https://ibb.co/jz0jJgk

I tried to do add this code in the title of the "local pickup" option in the Woocommerce>settings>shipping options but it doesn't show the custom store icon that I have.

```
Local Pickup <img src="examplesite.com/media/store_icon.png" alt="local store icon">
```

If this is possible... what code do I need to add at functions.php or in which file?

Thank you for reading.

**UPDATE**:

So far I have been using this (a useful tip provided by @Jainil)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) { 
        $shipping_method_id = ['flat_rate:19'];
        $label .= 'class="shipping_method"'('<img src="https://site.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/icon_store.png">', 'woocommerce');// Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      

    return $label; 
}
```

But it shows the icon in every shipping option available https://ibb.co/9ZJKVB8

I just want to show the icon in specific Local Pickup option.

Comment: ```woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php``` in the plugin folder this is the file that controls the shipping form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) { 
   // Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      

   if( $method->method_id == "flat_rate" ) {
       $label = $label."Your Icon Image";
   } else if( $method->method_id == "local_pickup" ) {
       $label = $label."Your Icon Image";       
   }
   return $label; 
}
```

Comment: Nice. thanks. Its almost perfect. I achieved to show the icon that I need, but it duplicates the icon in the three shipping options that I have available. (local pickup, free delivery and local delivery) I would like to show a different icon to each shipping options. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, use the condition with $method before return statement and change the $label variable accordingly.

Comment: @Trombas I have updated the code with the conditions.

Comment: hi again, hope you are having a great week. I have a doubt. Now I'm using different shipping options for different regions in my country. So I'm trying to add different icons for them. I'm adding the value of each method (for example 'flat_rate:23') but its not showing up in the custom shipping option, is showing all the flat rate in all regions. I want to how them in specific shipping methods. Is this possible? Thanks for reading.

Comment: @Trombas you can check condition with `$method->instance_id` for that.