# Add individual icon to each shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am trying to add a custom icon to every shipping option, to no avail.

I tried this answer: [Adding custom icons to the shipping options in Woocommerce Cart and Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225336/adding-custom-icons-to-the-shipping-options-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout).

And my code looks like this so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) { 
   // Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      

   if( $method->method_id == "shipping_method_0_flat_rate2" ) {
       $label = $label."https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/icon.png";

   }
   return $label; 
}
```

But it just doesn't work. I guess there is either issue in how I provide the path to the file or ID of the method.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked, if your if statement is true, so there is a value set to $label ? Just to make sure, it is not a problem of the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very near… You need to use `$method->id === "flat_rate:2"` instead of `$method->method_id == "shipping_method_0_flat_rate2"` in the IF statement.

Also you need, for the icon, to include the complete `<img>` html tag with the source link…

So in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {      
   // Targeting shipping method "Flat rate instance Id 2"
   if( $method->id === "flat_rate:2" ) {
       $label .= '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/icon.png" />';

   }

   return $label; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you. For future reference, if you don't mind. How should I know what goes into the $label object? If you can point me to some resources, I will be grateful.

Comment: How do you know, for example, what should be assigned to $label? I provided the URL, which is wrong. You knew it should be in tags. Where would I find this knowledge without asking here? What should I read?

Comment: The `$label` argument is not an object, but just the label name (string) that is displayed on cart and checkout pages for each available shipping method… On the other hand, the `$method` argument is the `WC_Shipping_Rate` object instance. Here are [all usable properties and methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html) for `WC_Shipping_Rate` Class.

Comment: @mgatner To find out how to change things like in this case, First try to look at WooCommerce related templates… Then in `cart/cart-shipping.php` template file you will find [on the line  40](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php#L40) the display for shipping methods label using the function `wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label()`… Then searching for that function you will fall [on this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label.html) and on its source code there is the right filter hook to use.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, the code works great. But can you edit it so that the logo appears before the shipping name?