# Change position of icons added to shipping methods Woocommcerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, icons

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225336/adding-custom-icons-to-the-shipping-options-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout) I added some icons to the shipping methods of a store I'm building. I used png images by using this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) { 
// Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      

if( $method->method_id == "flat_rate" ) {
   $label = $label.('<img src="https://www.website-link/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/002-truck.png">');
} else if( $method->method_id == "local_pickup" ) {
   $label = $label.('<img src="https://www.website-link/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/001- discount.png">');       
} 
return $label; 
}
```

There is one thing I would like to change, and I can't figure out how to do it. I want the icons to show next to the shipping method name. No it's underneath. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.
Vasco

Comment: Are these images large? Is there enough space for them to be in one line with text? How does they style?

Comment: I added your code to my WooCommerce store, and it displays on the same line next to the shipping method name for me.  It's likely a spacing issue for your particular theme like @IhorVyspiansky said above.  You'll just need to resize your image, change the text, widen the shipping box, etc.

Comment: Provide more details to be clear. As an option you might want to center your image vertically. It shouldn't be a problem as well - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/zYqBXYz?editors=1100

Comment: Sorry, the images were 24x24 px. I now changed it to 16x16 px, but still the same issue. You can see how it looks now (with the image below still 24x24 px to see the difference) in the screenshot. How does it works with the css? - https://imgur.com/a/Llj4Jpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `display` css property for your icons in your child theme's `style.css` file:

```css
#shipping_method label > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So you can test it in this code where styles are hard coded on the icons:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 10, 2 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label( $label, $method ) {
    $style = ' style="display:inline-block;"'; // Style applied to the thumbnails
    
    // Use the condition here with $method to apply the image to a specific method.      
    if( $method->method_id == "flat_rate" ) {
       $label = ' <img src="https://www.website-link/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/002-truck.png"'.$style.'> ' . $label;
    } else if( $method->method_id == "local_pickup" ) {
       $label = ' <img src="https://www.website-link/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/001-discount.png"'.$style.'> ' . $label;      
    } 
    return $label; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.